# Android Sync Adapter not firing in android nought (API > 23)

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-intent, android-sqlite

I need to connect the system server for each 1 minute from my mobile app to sync data. For that I am using `SyncAdapter` class in my app. It works fine for mobiles having *api < 23* (upto marshmallow it works fine). When I test my app in mobile having *api > 23* , the sync adapter class not firing. It fires only the first time I install the app in the device.

I am using the following code in my app. Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

```
public class MyServiceSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    //TODO change this constant SYNC_INTERVAL to change the sync frequency
    public static final int SYNC_INTERVAL               = 20; //60 * 180;       // 60 seconds (1 minute) * 180 = 3 hours
    public static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME               = SYNC_INTERVAL/3;
    private static final int MOVIE_NOTIFICATION_ID      = 3004;
    public static DataBaseConnection mCon;

    public MyServiceSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
        mCon = new DataBaseConnection(this.getContext());
    }

     @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

        Log.i("MyServiceSyncAdapter", "onPerformSync");
        //TODO get some data from the internet, api calls, etc.
        //TODO save the data to database, sqlite, couchbase, etc

        try{

            //my code to perform the task

        }catch (Exception e){

        }

    }

   public static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
        Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
        String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
            SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder()
                    .syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime)
                    .setSyncAdapter(account, authority)
                    .setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
            ContentResolver.requestSync(request);

        } else {
            ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
        }
    }

    public static void syncImmediately(Context context) {
        Log.i("MyServiceSyncAdapter", "syncImmediately");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(getSyncAccount(context), context.getString(R.string.content_authority), bundle);
    }


    public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {
        AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE); // Get an instance of the Android account manager
        Account newAccount = new Account(context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type)); // Create the account type and default account

        // If the password doesn't exist, the account doesn't exist
        if (accountManager.getPassword(newAccount) == null) {
            if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
                Log.e("MyServiceSyncAdapter", "getSyncAccount Failed to create new account.");
                return null;
            }
            onAccountCreated(newAccount, context);
        }
        return newAccount;
    }

    private static void onAccountCreated(Account newAccount, Context context) {
        Log.i("MyServiceSyncAdapter", "onAccountCreated");
        MyServiceSyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);
        syncImmediately(context);
    }

    public static void initializeSyncAdapter(Context context) {
        Log.d("MyServiceSyncAdapter", "initializeSyncAdapter");
        getSyncAccount(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the adapter is not firing and not just taking a very long time to run? From the documentation for [syncPeriodic](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncRequest.Builder.html#syncPeriodic(long,%20long)):

> > **pollFrequency**     long: the amount of time in seconds that you wish to elapse between periodic syncs. A minimum period of 1 hour is enforced.

So, if you wait long enough, you may see your periodic sync start. I have timed this (slow day) and the sync does start...eventually.

**Update**
Based upon a demo sync app [here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/SyncTrouble), I recorded `onPerformSync()` start times for APIs 23, 24 and 28. Times in the following table have been normalized to midnight. The sync period in all cases is attempted at one minute.

[image]

As you can see, `onPerformSync()` runs about once per minute for API 23. However, API 24 and API 28 do seem to latch the time between calls to `onPerformSync()` at 15 minutes give or take. APIs earlier than API 23 honor the one minute period request.

Recently, I haven't seen the one hour minimum, but I am sure I have in the past.

You may want to look into other ways to do syncing depending upon your requirements. Take a look at [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager), [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) and [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) in that order. (Use `WorkManager` if you can though.)